# Unable to add new application to Vungle

Tags: coronasdk, vungle-ads

Dears,

As mentioned in Vungle Docs https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/210468678 there must be "Add New Application" link on the main dashboard. I am not sure why it is not appearing on my account.
[account screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIdJ1.png)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My name is aki and I am an Integration Engineer at Vungle.

Sorry to hear that you have an issue with Vungle.
If the issue still exist, can you please repot this with your AppID to tech-support@vungle.com?
So, I can help you.

Thanks so much!
-aki